# AngularJS Select from Json (similiar to MySQL)

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, json

I have a json:

```
{"sectionTitle":"Account Information","sectionItems":[{"itemTitle":"Balance","url":"/account/balance","selected":true},{"itemTitle":"Account Statement","url":"/account/statementsearch","selected":false},{"itemTitle":"Deposit","url":"/account/deposit","selected":false},{"itemTitle":"Withdrawal","url":"/account/withdraw","selected":false},{"itemTitle":"Edit Profile","url":"/account/editprofile","selected":false},{"itemTitle":"Change Password","url":"/account/changepassword","selected":false}]}
```

Now I just want to check if there is an item (child) inside `sectionTitle` where selected is true.

Something like this in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM sectionItems WHERE selected=true
```

Can I do something similar in angular js, so I can check if the the parents has children?

I hope you understood my question.

This is my html

```
            <nav class="sidebar-nav">
                    <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu-help">

                        <li ng-repeat="menuItem in accountCtrl.menuStructure">
                            <a class="{{ (menuItem.sectionItems.length > 0) ?  'metisHasChildren' : '' }}" href="/en/help-area/poker-help/poker-rules/">
                                <span ng-if="menuItem.sectionItems.length > 0" class="fa arrow fa fa-angle-double-down"></span>
                                {{ ::menuItem.sectionTitle }}
                                {{ ::menuItem }}
                                </a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse in">
                                    <li ng-repeat="subMenuItem in menuItem.sectionItems" ng-click="accountCtrl.changePage(subMenuItem.url)">
                                        <a ng-class="(subMenuItem.selected) ? 'page-active' : ''">{{ ::subMenuItem.itemTitle }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

Comment: you could use Linq query

Comment: Is there any other methods to do without installing any additional libraries?

Comment: I don't think you need additional libraries to use Linq

Comment: try `var result = JSONstr.where({ selected: true });`

Comment: try this `data.sectionItems.filter(function(x){ return x.selected;}).length`;

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to anything fancy to get this working. Simply convert the json to an object and access the property you want using dot notation. So for example:

```
var json          = JSON.parse(json);
var selectedItems = [];

angular.forEach(json.sectionItems, function(sectionItem) {
    if (sectionItem.selected) {
        selectedItems.push(sectionItem);
    }
});
```

Would convert the json string to an object and then loop over each `sectionItem` child, check for `selected` is true and create an array of matching items.

Comment: I need to check sectionItems length where selected is true only

Comment: Updated answer to select only true items. You need to use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a forEach loop.  This example will return an array of all sectionItems where selected equals true, but you can return whatever you'd like.

```
$scope.items =[];
angular.forEach(sectionItems, function(item){
  if (item.selected === true){
    $scope.items.push(item);
  }
})
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/GURIYo5s5dKdZBQzAL06?p=preview)

To make this work inline with ng-repeat you will use it in a filter, like this:

```
app.filter('menuFilter', function() {

  return function(menuItems) {
    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(menuItems, function(menuItem) {
      angular.forEach(menuItem.sectionItems, function(item) {
        if (item.selected === true) {
          filtered.push(menuItem);
        }
      });
    });

    return filtered;
  }
});
```

And change your markup, like this:

```
ng-repeat="menuItem in accountCtrl.menuStructure | menuFilter "
```

Comment: not bad, but is it possible to do that inline in html?

Comment: It is, but what HTML specifically?  Are you using an ng-repeat, or ng-options, or something else?

Comment: I have a metis menu, where i have to check if there is selected submenus inside, if there is selected than A specific class will be added to the parent.

Comment: Ok, can you include that html in your question?

Comment: I've added the HTML, i have to add class selected to the parent <li>

Comment: Ok, so you want this logic applied to the first ng-repeat or the second?

Comment: Ok, give me a minute

Comment: @RuslanDascal - I've updated my answer based on the context your provided with your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to do any custom filter or anything like that, just use the **standard** *filter*, as below:

```
<li ng-repeat="menuItem in accountCtrl.menuStructure | filter: { sectionItems: { selected: true } }"> {{ menuItem.sectionTitle }}
```

*Working* **demo**:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('accountController', function() {
    var vm = this;
  
    vm.menuStructure = [  
       {  
          "sectionTitle":"Account Information",
          "sectionItems":[  
             {  
                "itemTitle":"Balance",
                "url":"/account/balance",
                "selected":true
             },
             {  
                "itemTitle":"Account Statement",
                "url":"/account/statementsearch",
                "selected":false
             },
             {  
                "itemTitle":"Deposit",
                "url":"/account/deposit",
                "selected":false
             },
             {  
                "itemTitle":"Withdrawal",
                "url":"/account/withdraw",
                "selected":false
             },
             {  
                "itemTitle":"Edit Profile",
                "url":"/account/editprofile",
                "selected":false
             },
             {  
                "itemTitle":"Change Password",
                "url":"/account/changepassword",
                "selected":false
             }
          ]
       },
       {  
          "sectionTitle":"Account Information 2",
          "sectionItems":[  
             {  
                "itemTitle":"Balance",
                "url":"/account/balance",
                "selected":false
             },
             {  
                "itemTitle":"Account Statement",
                "url":"/account/statementsearch",
                "selected":false
             },
             {  
                "itemTitle":"Deposit",
                "url":"/account/deposit",
                "selected":false
             },
             {  
                "itemTitle":"Withdrawal",
                "url":"/account/withdraw",
                "selected":false
             },
             {  
                "itemTitle":"Edit Profile",
                "url":"/account/editprofile",
                "selected":false
             },
             {  
                "itemTitle":"Change Password",
                "url":"/account/changepassword",
                "selected":false
             }
          ]
       }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="accountController as accountCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="menuItem in accountCtrl.menuStructure | filter: { sectionItems: { selected: true } }"> {{ menuItem.sectionTitle }}
      <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse in">
        <li ng-repeat="subMenuItem in menuItem.sectionItems" ng-click="accountCtrl.changePage(subMenuItem.url)">
          <a ng-class="{ 'page-active': subMenuItem.selected }" ng-bind="::subMenuItem.itemTitle"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

**Tips:**

1. Instead of using `ngClass` with `ternary` operator, you can simply use this way:

```
ng-class="{ 'page-active': subMenuItem.selected }"
```

2. Even if works in this way that you're using, I'd recommend you to take a look on the [**special-repeats**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points), it fits really well in your situation.

I hope it helps!!

Answer (score -1):

```
var JSONStr=[{"sectionTitle":"Account Information","sectionItems":[{"itemTitle":"Balance","url":"/account/balance","selected":true},{"itemTitle":"Account Statement","url":"/account/statementsearch","selected":false},{"itemTitle":"Deposit","url":"/account/deposit","selected":false},{"itemTitle":"Withdrawal","url":"/account/withdraw","selected":false},{"itemTitle":"Edit Profile","url":"/account/editprofile","selected":false},{"itemTitle":"Change Password","url":"/account/changepassword","selected":false}]}];
var result = JSONStr.where({ selected: true });
```